# Project in MongoDB Aggregation Framework

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am trying to use the $project operator in the aggregation-framework with MongoDB for Java.

```
DBObject fields = new BasicDBObject("example", 1);
fields.put("timestamp", $timestampField);
```

The above results in "exception: Unrecognized pipeline stage name: 'timestamp'" , "code" : 16436 , "ok" : 0.0}

Answer (score 0):

If what you are trying to **`$project`** is basically something that serializes like this:

```
{ "$project": {
    "example": 1,
    "timestamp": "$timestameField"
}}
```

Then you construct your BSON accordingly, and pretty much exactly as shown:

```
DBObject project = new BasicDBObject(
    "$project", new BasicDBObject(
        "example", 1
    ).append(
        "timestamp", "$timestamp"
    )
);
```

It is the `.append()` method that adds additional field content. The `.put()` method "replaces" the content in the BasicDBObject.